# Learning precedence for mod rewrite

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect some old links to new locations.  I am using wordpress.

I added these lines to the top of my .htaccess files because I want URLs of the format
authors/NNNNN/WORDS-GO_HERE to map to /?author=NNNN
articles/NNNN/WORDS-GO_HERE to map to /?p=NNNN

The second one works fine, but the author one does not.  If I type the querystring in my browser it finds the authors, but if I try www.myurl.com/authors/NNNNN/blah I get a not found.

Finally, when there was an article with the title Authors should Publish, the URLs that were looking for authors would redirect to that article.  I renamed the article and reset its slug, and now I get the not found error.

Any ideas?  I would like to become a master of rewrite, but I am not off to a good start.

Cheers

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^authors/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /?author=$1 [N]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /?p=$1 [N]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```